# Animation starts only after I've touched the screen

Tags: android, animation, fragment

I have a layout with a top bar container and a content container. When clicking on a button in the top bar, a vertical menu is displayed using an animation. My `minSdkVersion` is 9.

This works well when I start the app and I still haven't clicked a menu button (i.e. the content fragment has not changed), but as soon as I have clicked an option (and then replace the fragment in the content_container), the vertical menu behaves erratically. The click event of the menu btn is properly triggered, but the vertical menu is not always shown (but sometimes it is...). However, when I click the button and then touch the screen, the animation (show or hide the menu) starts.

I guess it has something to do with the vertical menu overlapping the content fragment, and then replacing the content fragment modify it in some way, but I can't find any solution.

Anybody can help?

**top bar fragment**

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        toggleMenu(0);      

        Button btn_menu = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_menu);
        btn_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mVerticalMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                toggleMenu(1000);
            }
        });
    }

    private void toggleMenu(int duration){
        if(mMenuIsOpen){

            TranslateAnimation anim1 = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,-(mHeight-mMenuVerticalOffset));
            anim1.setFillAfter(true);
            anim1.setDuration(duration);
            mVerticalMenu.setAnimation(anim1);

            AlphaAnimation anim2 = new AlphaAnimation(0.7f, 0.0f);
            anim2.setFillAfter(true);
            anim2.setDuration(duration);            

            menu_option_01.setOnClickListener(null);
            menu_option_02.setOnClickListener(null);
            menu_option_03.setOnClickListener(null);

            mMenuIsOpen = false;
        }
        else{

            TranslateAnimation anim1 = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,-(mHeight-mMenuVerticalOffset),0);
            anim1.setFillAfter(true);
            anim1.setDuration(duration);
            mVerticalMenu.setAnimation(anim1);

            AlphaAnimation anim2 = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 0.7f);
            anim2.setFillAfter(true);
            anim2.setDuration(duration);

            menu_option_01.setOnClickListener(mButtonClickListener);
            menu_option_02.setOnClickListener(mButtonClickListener);
            menu_option_03.setOnClickListener(mButtonClickListener);

            mMenuIsOpen = true;
        }

    }



    private OnClickListener mButtonClickListener = new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            toggleMenu(1000);

            if(!v.isSelected()){        


                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                switch(v.getId()){

                case R.id.menu_option_01:

                    // replace content_container by fragment 1

                    break;

                case R.id.btn_02:

                    // replace content_container by fragment 2

                    break;      

                case R.id.btn_03:

                    // replace content_container by fragment 3

                    break;      

                }
            }
        }

    };

    private OnClickListener mBgClickListener = new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            toggleMenu(1000);           
        }
    };
```

**Main layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="44dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_bar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**top bar layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00000000" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/vertical_menu"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

      <!-- menu layout -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_menu"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:background="@drawable/menubtn" />   

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Just a clarification: at first the menu works great. You open the menu and select an item which will trigger a replace of the content fragment(at this point the menu is closed, right?). Then you click again on the menu button(which doesn't open? but if you click the background the menu opens?)

Comment: At first the menu works. Then after the content has been modified, the menu opens/closes after a click on the menu button only if I touch the screen anywhere after the click. I found a solution though (see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of my `Toggle` method, I invalidate the root view:

```
rootView.invalidate();
```

and now it works. Not quite clear why I must do that though...

Comment: I know this is old but I'm having the same problem... Any new way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

I know there is already an accepted answer for this but I had a similar problem and the answer didnt help.

I had a view that I declared at the end of my layout to keep its Z index above its siblings. I had to touch the page to make the animation work.

So I set the Z index again through Java and it worked.

```
view.bringToFront();
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem and tried to add this before the animation was called but no luck...Is there any new way to deal with this?