# Animation listerener not called after fragment change

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-animation

I have a main activitiy containing a fragment. This fragment can be changed by selecting a menu item. 
When on the first fragment, clicking the menu button. The side bar is shown. After selecting a menu item, the fragment changes. 
When you click the menu item on this fragment, the animation listeren is not called instantly. You first have to scroll in a direction before it calles the script. 
The menu item is in the main activity, so it should mind if there would be a different Fragment, right?

```
    slideIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_in);
slideIn.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {


@Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            isAnimating = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            animation.setDuration((long) 0.1f);
            menuView.startAnimation(animation);
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) menuView.getLayoutParams();
            p.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            menuView.setLayoutParams(p);
            isAnimating = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

menuView.startAnimation(slideIn);
```

And this would be the fragment change:

```
trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            trans.remove((Fragment) Globals.getInstance().getCurrentFragment());
                            trans.add(R.id.realtabcontent, fragmentName, "tag");
                            trans.commit();
```

So on the different fragment, the animation is started as soon as I scroll. The above code is all in the Main Activity

Comment: Your `TranslateAnimation(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)` is `new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);`. So the start and end X,Y coordinates are the same. So there will be no translation to show. And what are you trying to do after slide in animation?

Comment: The location of the menu will be reset to the starting position after the animation has ended, you could see this happen before the new location was set. The translation in the onEnd makes sure you won't see the flickering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view was not drawn yet, so it only started after an input.
The anwser was that I had to Invalidate() my Root Layout.

Credits go to [Jul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/326849/jul) 
[Animation starts only after I've touched the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133609/animation-starts-only-after-ive-touched-the-screen#answer-16141453)